# Django bulk update setting each to different values?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Is it possible to update multiple objects with on db call, but setting each selected item to a different value?

I know it can be done with the same value

```
my_articles = models.Article.objects.filter(...)
for article in my_articles:
    article.name = 'foo'
    article.save()

# is equivalent to
models.Article.objects.filter(...).update(name='foo')
```

But what if I want to do something like this?

```
my_articles = models.Article.objects.filter(...)
for article in my_articles:
    article.name = get_new_name_for_this_one_article(article)
    article.save()

# is equivalent to
???
```

Im using the mysql backend if that matters at all

Comment: There is no such way. You have to iterate.

Comment: On the contrary. There maybe lots of different ways. But your question isn't clear enough. You need to post concrete code

Comment: What does `get_new_name_for_this_one_article`?

Comment: @e4c5 it is my impression that the question is clear. I have a similar situation where I wish to update the database based on `request.POST` data, and reduce the number of commits to the database. I know that in sqlalchemy one can modify any number of rows and then commit everything all at once.